# Passing dictionary index as variable to url in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to pass a string stored in a dictionary to url to be used as a variable. I want it to be passed to the function the url is pointing to. I tried putting it in `{{ post.username }}` but it won't accept it. Currently, I have it in quotes as `"post.username"` but it accepts is as the literal string and not the string stored in the dictionary. Any help would be appreciated.

### Template

```
    {% for post in posts %} 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="card" style="width: 40rem;">
            <div class="card-header bg-white"> 
              <a href='{% url "user_view" "post.username" %}'><img class="rounded-circle" src="{{ post.user_image }}" style="width:30px; height: 30px;">  {{ post.user_name }}</a>
              <div class="text-black-50 mt-2">{{ post.created_date }} ago</div>
            </div>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.picture }}" alt="Post Image" style="width: 100%; height: 30vw; object-fit: cover">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">{{ post.description }}</p>
              <a href="">Comments | {{ post.comments }}</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        </div>
      </div>
```

### URL

`path('user_view/<account_id>', views.user_view, name='user_view')`
I tried `path('user_view/<str:account_id>'` but no luck

### View

```
def user_view(request, account_id):
    user = User.objects.get(username=account_id)
    user_prop = UserProperty.objects.get(user_id=user)
    account_info = [user_prop.profile_photo, account_id, user_prop.bio]
    print(account_info)

    return render(request, 'users/user_view.html', {'account_info': account_info})
```

When I click on the anchor on the website, it gives me this address : http://localhost:8000/user_view/post.username

Comment: `{%` is enough, no need for additional `{{` inside

Comment: It won't work with {{ or if I leave it alone, it only works when I pass it a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<a href="/user_view/{{post.username}}"><img class="rounded-circle" src="{{ post.user_image }}" style="width:30px; height: 30px;">  {{ post.user_name }}</a>
```

In your urls:

```
path('user_view/<str:account_id>/'
```

Comment: I get Page not found (404)

Comment: Where did the link send you to? Try in the urls 'user_view/<str:account_id>/ ...'

Comment: I restarted the server with your changes it works! thank you so much!

Comment: This advice is misleading, one should not build urls manually, url reversing must work.